# Mongodb service startup problem on Ubuntu 22.04 (coredump)

Tags: mongodb

Installed `mongodb` on Ubuntu 22.04 but when starting (`systemctl start mongod`) it it crashes.

Diagnostics:

`systemctl status mongod`:

```
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Thu 2023-02-16 12:49:07 GMT; 6min ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 14497 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
   Main PID: 14497 (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
        CPU: 14ms

Feb 16 12:49:07 ax100 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Feb 16 12:49:07 ax100 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=4/ILL
Feb 16 12:49:07 ax100 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

`journalctl  -xe` (end):

```
Feb 16 12:49:07 ax100 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mongod.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit mongod.service has finished successfully.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 19169.
Feb 16 12:49:07 ax100 kernel: traps: mongod[14497] trap invalid opcode ip:560a33fd049a sp:7ffc3e0de3b0 error:0 in mongod[560a2f084000+6232000]
Feb 16 12:49:07 ax100 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=4/ILL
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mongod.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'dumped' and its exit status is 4.
Feb 16 12:49:07 ax100 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit mongod.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'core-dump'.
```

`systemctl sart mongod` doesn't produce a `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` file either... (weird...)

The `/etc/mongod.conf` is:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
  engine: wiredTiger
#   wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: rs01

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

`ldd /usr/bin/mongod` produces:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff4fb61000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f6594a4e000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f6594a23000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f6594a0f000)
    libcrypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 (0x00007f65945cc000)
    libssl.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3 (0x00007f6594528000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6594441000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f659441f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f65941f7000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f659b303000)
    libnghttp2.so.14 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x00007f65941cd000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f65941ac000)
    librtmp.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0x00007f659418d000)
    libssh.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4 (0x00007f6594120000)
    libpsl.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpsl.so.5 (0x00007f659410a000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f65940b6000)
    libldap-2.5.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap-2.5.so.0 (0x00007f6594057000)
    liblber-2.5.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.5.so.0 (0x00007f6594046000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007f6593f77000)
    libbrotlidec.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x00007f6593f69000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f6593f4b000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f6593da1000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f6593bb6000)
    libhogweed.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.6 (0x00007f6593b6e000)
    libnettle.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.8 (0x00007f6593b28000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f6593aa4000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f65939d9000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f65939aa000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f65939a4000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f6593996000)
    libsasl2.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007f6593979000)
    libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x00007f6593956000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f659381b000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f6593803000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f65937fc000)
    libffi.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8 (0x00007f65937ed000)
```

Have compiled mongodb from source (on Ubuntu 20.04) with `--dbg=on`, loading and running the server in the `gdb` debugger, produces:

```
(venv-mongodb) software@ax100:[mongo]: gdb build/install/home/software/inst/mongodb/6.2/bin/mongod
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from build/install/home/software/inst/mongodb/6.2/bin/mongod...
warning: File "/home/software/src/mongodb/mongo/.gdbinit" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
To enable execution of this file add
    add-auto-load-safe-path /home/software/src/mongodb/mongo/.gdbinit
line to your configuration file "/home/software/.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
    set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "/home/software/.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
    info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/software/src/mongodb/mongo/build/install/home/software/inst/mongodb/6.2/bin/mongod 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
tcmalloc::PageHeap::IncrementalScavenge (this=0x5555693716c0 <tcmalloc::Static::pageheap_>, n=256) at src/third_party/gperftools/dist/src/page_heap.cc:442
442   const double rate = FLAGS_tcmalloc_release_rate;
(gdb)
```

Not sure what's going on... Anyone some idea what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. What do the logs say? Did you mess with the systemd file? From which repo did you install mongo?

Comment: I followed the procedure from: `https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/`

Comment: Have a look at the logfile, typically at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: The try `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` and see what the output is.

Comment: Wernfried, in anwer to your suggestion:
`mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`: `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`

This is now on Ubuntu 20.04 (... i.e. I've gone back to an Ubuntu version for which I have mongodb working on a laptop -- the hardware I'm trying to install it on is a "10 year old" Dell PowerEdge R610 blade server -- could it be a hardware issue...?

Answer (score 1):

This is a symptom of a cpu flag missing. When running virtualized (Proxmox/KVM) with CPU "QEMU64" I can reproduce the "Illegal instruction trap" :

> [   19.105154] traps: mongod[565] trap invalid opcode ip:55883387526a sp:7ffdd5d4b480 error:0 in mongod[55882e8f5000+626c000]

When running with cpu "host", mongodb starts ok.

Comment: I solved it by compiling the MongoDB 6.0 source code with the -march=westmere flag (consistent with a Dell Poweredge R630 CPU architecture).